# Extra error on unit test in Xcode

Tags: cocoa, unit-testing, xcode

I always have a extra error when I try check if my expected error appear in my unit test.

First appear this error:
"command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1"
then my expected error.

Is this normal, I'll always see the first error?

Comment: What unit testing framework are you using?

Comment: OCUnit, they come with XCode.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do much about it. That is the way it works.